# BeanCurrentlyInCreationException after upgrading Boot to 2.6

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

After upgrading my project to Spring Boot `2.6.0`, I'm getting the following exception during startup:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:355) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:227) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:410) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
```

However, my configuration seems to be in line with Spring documentation ([HttpSecurity setup](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.3/reference/html5/#oauth2login-provide-websecurityconfigureradapter), [AuthenticationManagerBuilder setup](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#hello-web-security-java-configuration) and [PasswordEncoder setup](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.15.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-authentication-userdetailsservice)):

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .mvcMatchers("/presentations")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin();
    }
    
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("testuser")
            .password(encoder().encode("password"))
            .roles("READ");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Having a closer look at my implementation, it seems the `@Autowired` method calling the `@Bean` `PasswordEncoder` method is generating this issue (this doesn't happen if I call the method from within another `@Bean` definition method).

The solution was then to move the logic to a different `@Configuration` class:

```
@Configuration
public class UsersSetup {
    
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth, PasswordEncoder encoder) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("testuser")
        .password(encoder.encode("password"))
        .roles("READ");
    }
}
```

The reason why this appeared with the new Boot version is because Boot now doesn't try to break the dependency cycle automatically by default any more:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.6-Release-Notes#circular-references-prohibited-by-default

As an alternative, I could also revert this feature to its former behavior by including the following application property in my project:

```
spring.main.allow-circular-references=true
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can declare the factory method for the password encoder as `static`. This allows to stick to one configuration class for configuring Spring Security.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error and able to resolve it by using overridden configure method instead of autowired configureGlobal.

Replaced this

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("testuser")
        .password(encoder().encode("password"))
        .roles("READ");
}
```

with this

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("testuser")
            .password(encoder().encode("password"))
            .roles("READ");
}
```

Comment: This solves our problem when we are migrating to a newer Spring Boot version.

Answer (score 0):

I had taken your problem too. I solved this problem when I added `'spring.main.allow-circular-references=true'` into `appplication.properties.xml`.

**Using New Spring WebSecurtyConfig Above Version 2.7.0+**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws 
Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic();
        return http.build();

    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user")
                
.password(passwordEncoder().encode("password")).roles("USER");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

If you want to use to AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth parameter in configureGlobal function, this method can add
`'spring.main.allow-circular-references=true'` into `appplication.properties.xml`.

**OR, You can use this method**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)

public class WebSecurityConfig extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean 
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{   

    http.authorizeRequests()
           .anyRequest().authenticated()
           .and().httpBasic();
    return http.build();

}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    super.configure(auth);
}
   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change `public PasswordEncoder encoder()` to `static PasswordEncoder encoder()`